# IconButton with label

Tags: material-ui

Is there something I can use in/with [`IconButton`](https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/#iconbutton-api) to define a label below the icon in [Material UI 4](https://v4.mui.com/)?

Maybe something similar to [`BottomNavigationAction`](https://material-ui.com/api/bottom-navigation-action/) but without it having to be inside of a [`BottomNavigation`](https://material-ui.com/api/bottom-navigation/#bottomnavigation-api).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add your label as a direct child of the IconButton (sibling of the Icon itself), and override the IconButton-label style to have *flexDirection: column*

```
import React from 'react';
import {IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SaveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Save';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  iconButtonLabel: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
}));

export default function IconButtonWithLabel() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <IconButton classes={{label: classes.iconButtonLabel}}>
        <SaveIcon/>
        <div>
          hello
        </div>
      </IconButton>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: great work!! this helped me to overcome my problem

Answer (score 0):

The accepter answer is outdated, here's the new way to do it:

```
<Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}>
    Delete
</Button>>
```

there also the property endIcon that can be used to put the icon after the text.

Source with an example: [Link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#system-IconLabelButtons.js)

Comment: Hmm... My question was specific to the version 4 in which case I believe the accepted answer holds true. I'll update the question to specify MUI version.